# Node.js to Javascript\Jquery passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

How do I pass a variable from my server.js file to another js file. This is my server.js(pie.html calls the js file).

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(), 
    path = require("path");

var newVar = "Hello, world."

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/pie'));

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile((path.join(__dirname + '/views/pie/pie.html')));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

And here is my pie.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oldVar = "OldVar...";
    //oldVar = newVar
    alert(oldVar);//"Hello, world."
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant directly pass variables from server to browser because this javascript files executes in different processes (and probably on different machines). Use ajax or websockets (http://socket.io/) to pass data between server and client. Good Luck!